# How to send "Your session expired" once, after client logged out automatically in Express + Passport

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js

I am using Express, Passport and SequelizeSessionStore to enable user login and session perserve.
I have configuration that automatically logout user when he not refreshed website for more than 30 minutes. User is redirected to login page.

How to inform user about this? How I can dig information from passport or express right after user is logged out to create alert message on fronmtend? I want it just once and just when user is logged out automatically.

EDIT: Seems that SequelizeSessionStore just remove session from database after configured time. I can't find a way how to distinguish between normal logout and automatic logout

Comment: Maybe you could setTimeout with 30min an trigger the alert in your login function, that could be a workaround.

Comment: Yea but session is refreshed every API call and so, so it will be very difficult to implement this... I want to find rather a server side way to distinguish between normal logout and automatic logout